# GSAP TimelineLite finish timeline instead of pause

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am using GSAP TimelineLite for a slider. I noticed that the slider messes up a bit when changing from one tab to another.

I solved this issue by using `Page Visibility API`. If the page is not active the timeline is paused, once the page is active again the timeline is resumed.

```
// page visibility    
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        tl.pause();
    }
    else {
        tl.resume();
    }
}
```

This works fine, however the timeline may still 'break' a bit if you change the tab in between sliders. I was wondering if there's something similar to jQuery's `finish` function instead of using `pause`.

I tried to use the `addPause` function, which by default, pauses the timeline at the end of the timeline. Can't seem to get it working so far.

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        tl.addPause();
    }
    else {
        tl.resume();
    }
}
```

I also tried using an `onComplete` function in the constructor and the final element in the timeline instead of pausing the timeline when the page is not active. But it seems like nothing is fired after switching to another tab, none of the console logs are displayed.

**Constructor:**

```
tl = new TimelineLite({
    onComplete: function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            console.log('timeline: pause');
            tl.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

**End of Timeline:**

```
tl
    .to(activeSliderText, 0.5, { opacity: 0 })
    .fromTo(activeSlider, 1, { x: 0 }, { x: animateTo, ease: Power1.easeInOut }, '-=0.25')
    .fromTo(newSlider, 0.9, { x: animateFrom }, { x: 0, ease: Power1.easeInOut }, '-=1')
    .fromTo(newSliderText, 0.5, { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1, onComplete: endOfTimeline }, '-=0.25');

var endOfTimeline = function() {
    console.log('end of timeline');
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log('timeline: pause');
        tl.pause();
    }
}
```